# Help on finding a fantasy series pre 2000s

Tags: story-identification

Thanks in advance! When I was an up and coming fantasy enthusiast, my younger self came across a really engrossing fantasy series about a female shapeshifter and her panther mate. I remember the cover, it had a lioness or female cougar on a cliff,with a blonde woman with tumbling blonde hair superimposed over the lioness. I cannot find it anywhere! Sos!

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can  add anything in, such as what year it may have been published, or when you read it (a little narrower than "pre 2000s" would help).